# how to split an element in python by keeping the separator

Tags: python

hi how can I split this string while keeping '(':

```
s = ' playsound3Dwhenpossible(soundspotpoint18, %$videos_sounds_path%/sounds/lavazza_-_auguri_cherubini__15_.mp3, true, false, -52.644483, 0.947368, 90, 1, spotpoint18);'
x = s.split("(")
print(x)
```

I also tried with:

```
x = s.split("?=(")
```

but it did not work.

thank you

Comment: What does 'keeping the separator' means in your case? The separator as a separate element of the resulting list or joined to one of the adjacent elements?

Comment: Well why do you want to keep separators? If you extract information from string usingg regular expression and group to extract them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the separator '(' in the output array, the simplest is to use a regex split.

```
import re
s = ' playsound3Dwhenpossible(soundspotpoint18, %$videos_sounds_path%/sounds/lavazza_-_auguri_cherubini__15_.mp3, true, false, -52.644483, 0.947368, 90, 1, spotpoint18);'
x = re.split(r'(\()', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to keep the separator, you can re-introduce it after the split:

```
def split_keep_separator(source, sep):
    elements = source.split(sep)
    return [e for t in zip(elements, [sep] * (len(elements))) for e in t][:-1]
```

And to test it:

```
s = ' playsound3Dwhenpossible(soundspotpoint18, %$videos_sounds_path%/sounds/lavazza_-_auguri_cherubini__15_.mp3, true, false, -52.644483, 0.947368, 90, 1, spotpoint18);'

x = split_keep_separator(s, "(")
print(x)

# [' playsound3Dwhenpossible',
#  '(',
#  'soundspotpoint18, %$videos_sounds_path%/sounds/lavazza_-_auguri_cherubini__15_.mp3, true, false, -52.644483, 0.947368, 90, 1, spotpoint18);']
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input string, It seems your expected output may be,

```
[' playsound3Dwhenpossible', '(soundspotpoint18, %$videos_sounds_path%/sounds/lavazza_-_auguri_cherubini__15_.mp3, true, false, -52.644483, 0.947368, 90, 1, spotpoint18);']
```

If so, this seems easiest to me

```
s = ' playsound3Dwhenpossible(soundspotpoint18, %$videos_sounds_path%/sounds/lavazza_-_auguri_cherubini__15_.mp3, true, false, -52.644483, 0.947368, 90, 1, spotpoint18);'
print s.replace("(","*(").split('*')
```

First replace and than split.

Instead of `'*'`, you can use whatever, which is **NOT** in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Another regex-based solution:

```
import re

s = ' playsound3Dwhenpossible(soundspotpoint18, %$videos_sounds_path%/sounds/lavazza_-_auguri_cherubini__15_.mp3, true, false, -52.644483, 0.947368, 90, 1, spotpoint18);'
splits = re.findall(r'(\(?[^(]+)', s)
print(splits)
```

Output:

```
[' playsound3Dwhenpossible', '(soundspotpoint18, %$videos_sounds_path%/sounds/lavazza_-_auguri_cherubini__15_.mp3, true, false, -52.644483, 0.947368, 90, 1, spotpoint18);']
```

Or if you want to have a generic (or easy to use) function:

```
split_keep = lambda s, sep : re.findall('({0}?[^{0}]+)'.format(re.escape(sep)), s)
splits = split_keep(s, '(')
```

This fails in the corner case of having multiple contiguous separators. The following slightly more complex function fixes it:

```
split_keep = lambda s, sep : re.findall('({0}[^{0}]*|{0}?[^{0}]+)'.format(re.escape(sep)), s)
print(split_keep('((asda((asfasf', '('))
```

Output:

```
['(', '(asda', '(', '(asfasf']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly change your split slightly to :

```
s = ' playsound3Dwhenpossible(soundspotpoint18, %$videos_sounds_path%/sounds/lavazza_-_auguri_cherubini__15_.mp3, true, false, -52.644483, 0.947368, 90, 1, spotpoint18);'

x = s.split(r'\(') #raw
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[' playsound3Dwhenpossible(soundspotpoint18, %$videos_sounds_path%/sounds/lavazza_-_auguri_cherubini__15_.mp3, true, false, -52.644483, 0.947368, 90, 1, spotpoint18);']
```